# How to disassemble this old faucet? faucet supply line is leaking which needs to be replaced

Tags: faucet

how do disassemble this old faucet? The faucet supply line leak needs to be replaced. please check the pics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you in fact disassembling the faucet (which does not fit with your reason) or do you just need to dismount it to change a hose (which fits with your reason, if you lack a wrench that will reach into the hole in the countertop.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal yea, I was trying to dismount the hose, but it was hard to reach and really tight. so, I wanna pull the faucet out, then dismount the hose.

Answer (score 2):

To dismount the faucet, normally that partly rusted bit on the center with the drain rod in it would be turned counter-clockwise until it's loose enough to fold and slide off without unthreading the whole way (which is what the hinge is about, normally.)

The black bits on either side of the screw are *possibly* indicating some other release action, such as squeezing them inwards towards the screw.

There are also specialist wrenches that can reach into a hole and unthread the supply lines in place, but dismounting may be easier and should not take any special tools.

You'll have to disconnect the lower end of the drain rod if dismounting the faucet, of course.

[image]

To start disassembling (rather than dismounting) such a faucet, you pry off the white parts and look for screws/nuts, but I don't think that's what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: the white part you mean the "cold" and "hot" cap on the faucet, it doesn't feel like it can be pried off, but I will give it a try. thanks.

Comment: lol, that was able to pry off but doesn't seem like able to disassemble the faucet. I uploaded pic, I will try to turn that rusted bit.

Comment: So if what you wanted to do was dismount it, why did you start with the "If disassembling" advice? Nothing up there will help to dismount it.