How to remove strange old restroom faucet, since I’m going to replace it with a new one

I seen many YouTube videos but none have a faucet mounting like the one I see on mine (has no screws and I tried pinching the black strips but nothing), I have no idea how to remove it. Please help me.

you need a special wrench that fits in the hole

This is similar to https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/257742/how-to-disassemble-this-old-faucet-faucet-supply-line-is-leaking-which-needs-to

Looks to me like the only thing holding it to the counter is that odd toggle wing.  Might be able to simply bash it loose.  If you're replacing the faucet, you only need to worry about damaging the sink and counter.  Or, maybe you cut away a little bit of the plywood so you can rotate the wings loose.  Have you tried pushing up or pulling down on the black plastic strips?
